# Including unmanaged ImageMagick dlls inside the .NET Wrapper

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to use the ImageMagick.NET wrapper in one of my Web Applications to compress, scale and crop JPEG files (I know there are a billion other libraries out there, but they are too slow for my needs). I believe I got the wrapper working (although it might have some memory corruption issues; but that's irrelevant to my question).

I don't have much experience with CLI, so I was wondering how I can get the wrapper to include all the required dependencies. Currently, you need to install ImageMagick and it creates a registry value with the file path that points to those dlls. The wrapper reads the registry and that's how it finds the dlls.

I want to circumvent that and have the wrapper just use the dlls when they are in the same root folder (no registry reading). Is this possible?

Here is the link to the wrapper that was created: http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/ (I don't think it was ever finished though, but complete enough for my needs).

Here is the link to what it is actually wrapping: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php